# Prism 4 WPF App - Solution Architecture with MVVM, Repositories and Unit of Work patterns implemented

Tags: wpf, prism, layer

I'm new to .Net and trying to learn things. I'm trying to develop a Prism4 WPF app with

1. Visual Studio CSharp 2010 Express Edition,
2. Prism v4,
3. Unity as IoC,
4. SQL Server CE as data store.

I've studied a lot(?) and infuenced by [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh580734.aspx) and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/ViewSwitchingAppsPrism4.aspx) among others, and decided to implement MVVM, Repository and UnitofWork patterns. This application will be a Desktop application with a single user (me:-)

So, I've created a solution with the following projects:

1. Shell (Application Layout and startup logic)
2. Common (Application Infrastructure and Workflow Logic)
3. BusinessModuleA (Views and ViewModels)
4. BusinessModuleA.Model (Business Entities - POCO)
5. BusinessModuleA.Data (Repositories, Data Access (EF?) )
6. BusinessModuleB (Views and ViewModels)
7. BusinessModuleB.Model (Business Entities - POCO)
8. BusinessModuleB.Data (Repositories, Data Access (EF?) )

My questions are:

1. Which projects should reference which projects ?
2. If I implement Repositories in 'BusinessModuleX.Data', which is
   obvious, where should I define IRepositories ?
3. Where should I define IUnitOfWork and where should I implement UnitOfWork ?
4. Is it ok if I consume UnitOfWork and Repositories in my ViewModels ?
   Instict says it is bad design.
5. If (4) above is bad, then ViewModel should get data via a Service
   Layer (another project ?). Then, how can we track changes to the
   entities so as to call the relevant CRUD methods on those objects at the Service Layer?
6. Is any of this making any sense or am I missing the big picture ?

---

Ok, may be I've not made myself clear on what I wanted exactly in my first post. There are not many answers coming up. I'm still looking for answers because while what @Rachel suggested may be effective for the immediate requirements, I want to be careful not to paint myself into a corner. I've an Access Db that I developed for my personal use at Office, and which became kind of a success and now being used by 50+ users and growing. Maintaining and modifying the access code base has been fairly simple at the beginning, but as the app evolved, began to fall apart. That's why I have chosen to re-write everything in .Net/Wpf/Prism and want to make sure that I get the basic design right.

Please discuss.

Meanwhile, I came up with [this...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh580734.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, I would simplify your project list a bit to just `Shell`, `Common`, `ModuleA`, and `ModuleB`. Inside each Project I'd have sub-folders to specify where everything is. For example, `ModuleA` might be separated into folders for `Views`, `ViewModels`, and `Models`

I would put all interfaces and global shared objects such as `IUnitOfWork` in your `Common` project, since it will be used by all modules.

How you implement `IUnitOfWork` and your `Repositories` probably depends on what your Modules are.

- If your entire application links to one database, or shares database objects, then I would probably create two more projects for the DataAccessLayer. One would contain public interfaces/classes that can be used by your modules, and the other would contain the actual implementation of the Data Access Layer, such as Entity Framework.
- If each Module has it's own database, or its own set of objects in the database (ie. Customer objects don't exist unless you have the Customer Module installed), then I would implement `IUnitOfWork` in the modules and have them handle their own data access. I would probably still have some generic interfaces in the `Common` library for the modules to build from though.

Ideally, all your modules and your `Shell` can access the `Common` library. Modules should not access each other unless they build on them. For example, a Customer Statistics module that builds on the base Customer module should access the Customer module.

As for if your ViewModels should consume a `UnitOfWork` or`Repository`, I would have them use a `Repository` only. Ideally your `Repository` should be like a black box - ViewModels can Get/Save data using the `Repository`, but should have no idea how it's implemented. Repositories can get the data from a service, entity framework, direct data access, or wherever, and the ViewModel won't care.

I'm no expert on design architecture, however that's how I'd build it :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Doesn't organising M-V-VM into folders but in the same project tightly couple them ? Yes, my modules each have their own db and are totally unrelated / unaware of other modules,except of course, 'Common'.

Comment: My 4th question is about using UnitOfWork 'and' Repositories not "or'. I think Repositories are constructor injected with a UnitOfWork to do their job. Also, allowing each module handle its own DataAccessLogic again couples everything airtight, right ? I wonder if that beats the very purpose of loose coupling and modular development that Prism and the patterns I listed above try to achieve.

Comment: @yoursvsr Objects can share a project and still be decoupled. For example, in MVVM the only references that should be made is your ViewModels referencing your Models, and your Views referencing Models/ViewModels. Where the actual objects exist doesn't really matter.

Comment: @yoursvsr And personally I usually don't separate my MVVM projects into separate folders for M, V, and VM. Instead I'll separate them into folders based on functionality. For example, Search Models, Search Views, and Search ViewModels will all share a folder. Others might argue differently, however that's my personal preference.

Comment: @yoursvsr I've handled Repositories in my ViewModels different ways depending on the situation. I've had the ViewModel create the Repository, I've passed the repository in through a constructor parameter, and I've used MEF to Import the Repository. Usually I'll have it reference the Repository interface and not the repository itself (ie. `ICustomerRepository` instead of `CustomerRepository`), although that depends on the size of the project.

Comment: Hi, also, doesn't allowing ViewModels consume Repositories/UnitOfWork results in directly referencing DataAccessLayer from the Presentation Layer? If I choose not to, how to fetch data into ViewModels ? Any best practices guidance here...? Any samples will help a lot. Thanks.

Comment: @yoursvsr Repositories are not necessarily your Data Access Layer. They're objects that usually reference the DAL, but they are not the DAL themselves.

Comment: ok, your way of organising a prism solution simplifies and makes my life easier for sure. I'm wondering if it remains the same when it comes to maintaining the app later on. I mean, what about the first link I've mentioned, 12 projects are there for a reason, or is it just overkill ?

Comment: @yoursvsr The reason I switched to grouping my projects by function instead of M, V, VM is because when I wanted to update something, it was obnoxious to hunt through each of the M, V, and VM libraries to make the update. Organize them by logical groupings and maintenance will be much easier.

Comment: @yoursvsr  Also, add new projects at logical bounderies between your code, not to organize them. Folders/Namespaces are for organizing while new projects are for boundaries. The biggest VS solution I worked on had about 10 projects (not counting modules), and each had their own purpose. Most of my smaller apps only have 1-3 projects depending on the need.

Comment: Hi, what if, down the road, I discover the need to re-use the Model for another brand-new module ? Or, change the View from WPF to Silverlight ?

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend you to get the [Introduction to PRISM](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=prism-introduction&highlight=brian-lagunas_prism1-01-intro%2a1,3,4,7,0,2,8,5,6!brian-lagunas_prism1-02-bootstrapper-shell%2a0,9,1,2,6,3,4,5,7,8!brian-lagunas_prism1-03-regions%2a0,1,2,4,6,3,5!brian-lagunas_prism1-04-modules%2a0,1,4,10,11,2,3,5,6,7,8,9!brian-lagunas_prism1-05-views%2a0,1,5,6,8,11,2,7,9,3,10,4!brian-lagunas_prism1-6-communication%2a0,1,2,4,6,8,10,12,3,5,7,11,9!brian-lagunas_prism1-07-state-based-navigation%2a0,5,4,1,2,3!brian-lagunas_prism1-08-view-based-navigation%2a0,13,1,3,5,6,7,9,11,2,4,8,10,12#prism1-01-intro) and Repository pattern inside [Design Patterns Library](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=patterns-library&highlight=scott-allen_pattern-repository%2a4,5!david-starr_pattern-strategy%2a3!john-sonmez_design-patterns-builder!donald-belcham_pattern-mediator%2a4!john-sonmez_design-patterns-visitor!john-sonmez_design-patterns-bridge!john-sonmez_design-patterns-interpreter!steve-smith_patterns-iterator%2a1!david-starr_pattern-facade%2a6!john-sonmez_design-patterns-composite!john-brown_dpl-observer!john-sonmez_design-patterns-prototype!john-brown_dpl-state!steve-smith_patterns-proxy!keith-brown_command-pattern!steve-smith_patterns-adapter!david-starr_pattern-null-object!brian-lagunas_decorator!john-brown_dpl-servicelocator!steve-smith_pattern-lazyload!david-starr_pattern-mvp!brian-lagunas_mvvm!glenn-block_pattern-event-aggregator%2a3,7,10!david-starr_pattern-introduction%2a2,3!david-starr_pattern-factories%2a4,7,10,5,6,8,9,11,12!niraj-bhatt_pattern-flyweight%2a5!scott-allen_pattern-unitofwork!robert-horvick_pattern-chain-of-responsibility#pattern-repository) training videos. They are great ones. Hope it helps